# Jar file or classes better for WAR file access

Tags: jsf-2, war, weblogic-10.x

Our application is JSF2 deployed in weblogic10.3.4 as war , In Prod environment , in a war file which would be better , to keep our application files as "class" files or packaged it as jar file.

Thanks
Vijay

Answer (score 0):

If you keep your classes in jar files within **/WEB-INF/lib** there would be no difference.

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not much clear. I understood you are not sure about deploying your entire application (including its dependencies) in a WAR file versus deploying your application as a WAR plus a JAR containing some of your dependencies. Right?

If you follow the second approach (using a JAR), you have an additional advantage (or burden) of being able to deploy them separately. It is a tradeoff, you should take into account which approach is better for you: deploying a single file gives you a "one-step" deployment, but makes you deploy your web app every time you need to deploy changes only to one of your dependencies.